# Change column types from text[] to integer[]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to change the column datatype from text array to integer array **mantaining the data** with no luck:

```
t.text "selectedextras", default: [], array: true
```

I've tried this, but it will give an exception:

```
LINE 1: ...UMN "selectedextras" TYPE integer[] USING REPLACE(translate(...
```

Migration:

```
class ChangeSelectedExtrasToInteger < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    change_column :campaigns, :selectedextras, :integer, array: true, default: [], using: "REPLACE(translate(selectedextras, '[]', '{}'), '\"', '')::int[]"
  end

  def down
    change_column :campaigns, :selectedextras, :text, array: true, default: [], using: "('[' || array_to_string(selectedextras, ', ') || ']')"
  end
end
```

Comment: Are all the values in "selectedextras" actually integers? If so then you should be able to just go with `using: 'selectedextras::integer[]'` [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d3692/1)

Comment: @engineersmnky OP also has default empty array

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need migration like this

```rb
def up
  execute <<~SQL
    ALTER TABLE campaigns
    ALTER COLUMN selectedextras DROP DEFAULT,
    ALTER COLUMN selectedextras SET DATA TYPE integer[] USING selectedextras::integer[],
    ALTER COLUMN selectedextras SET DEFAULT '{}'::integer[];
  SQL
end

def down
  execute <<~SQL
    ALTER TABLE campaigns
    ALTER COLUMN selectedextras DROP DEFAULT,
    ALTER COLUMN selectedextras SET DATA TYPE text[] USING selectedextras::text[],
    ALTER COLUMN selectedextras SET DEFAULT '{}'::text[];
  SQL
end
```

or more ActiveRecord way

```rb
def up
  change_column_default :campaigns, :selectedextras, nil
  change_column :campaigns, :selectedextras, :integer, array: true, using: 'selectedextras::integer[]'
  change_column_default :campaigns, :selectedextras, []
end

def down
  change_column_default :campaigns, :selectedextras, nil
  change_column :campaigns, :selectedextras, :text, array: true, using: 'selectedextras::text[]'
  change_column_default :campaigns, :selectedextras, []
end
```

One of the problem is that PostgreSQL can't replace `DEFAULT` from empty text array to empty integer array

If you will try just to apply query without removing default, you will get something like

```
ERROR:  default for column "selectedextras" cannot be cast automatically to type integer[]
```

The `USING` option of `SET DATA TYPE` can actually specify any expression involving the old values of the row; that is, it can refer to other columns as well as the one being converted

This allows very general conversions to be done with the `SET DATA TYPE` syntax

Because of this flexibility, the `USING` expression is not applied to the column's default value (if any); the result might not be a constant expression as required for a default

This means that when there is no implicit or assignment cast from old to new type, `SET DATA TYPE` might fail to convert the default even though a `USING` clause is supplied

In such cases, drop the default with `DROP DEFAULT`, perform the `ALTER TYPE`, and then use `SET DEFAULT` to add a suitable new default

`SET DEFAULT` affects the behavior of subsequent `INSERT` and `UPDATE` commands; it does not cause rows already in the table to change

You can read more in [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)